# Mock CompletableFuture supplyAsync method that updating member variable

Tags: java, asynchronous, mocking

**Background:** Using completableFuture for async call and then accepting the result and updating member variable.

**Scenario:** There might be chances that before async call get completed another method is trying to access that member variable. So how should I handle that situation in Mockito as well as in Real implementation? And can't wait using get and join method.

```
Class Proxy{

    Private Boolean isConfigured;

    Private void initConfigured(){
     
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(//some api call)
               .thenAccept((config) ->{ 
  
                  isConfigured = config;
               });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What should I do to handle the scenario (mentioned above) in unit test case?